# is the 'magical'/spiritual world another dimension of mind and thus an illusion

Tags: personal-practice, meditation

I have a question. is the 'magical'/spiritual world another dimension of mind and thus an illusion to leave through meditation whether it is obviously part of life and not one men's mind time?
in my experience, I'm very happy and easily, but still straggle with 'the magical/spiritual world (sorry I don't use scholars words, or being careful enough) starts to be clearer and nice. I start to like it after many years. but I still got the feeling - although its my daily reality, and I need to deal with it in the best way I can and learn it - that it might be also a level of illusion, that I have to get out of. I still like the simple life. its easier and lovely enough... so I'm between - 1. maybe that is my ego denying the real truth... should I focus on something special, or just go on with this nice tour. 2. I admit, a lot of that is west of time for me when it comes to others differences: like again and again. ok there is no me, but we know that already, and your angry still, and I'm tiered, or at that point I don't know what to do.... the good side is the 'little monks' (nick name) with them its at home and happy, joy, not u me, and good perspective, wisdom... but because of the duality, pleasant not pleasant... it always like maybe I should stop talking at all - like treat all of that like mind, time - yes not only mine, but still the same, and just let it flow in silence, meditate. is that the answer? it sounds like a good answer. is it to lie, to insist emptiness is the truth, or sort of miss understanding the world.
thank you <3

Comment: tnk you my friends. I have to practice the metta suta. I realize my week spots. and things moves better and better now. you all took me back to my heart and the way to the stable silent place I'm looking for. giving with love, and recognizing it more in more in every place. thank you. love you with all my heart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sacredness and spiritualism are states of being that we can never fully analyse or rationalise.  It can be felt deep within ones self, but this feeling cannot be captured fully by using words.  The way of the sacred, as Lao Tzu have said “is like a well, used but never used up.  It is like the eternal void, filled with infinite possibilities.  It is hidden but always present.”

One of 20th century eastern philosophers, J. Krishnamurti saw the spiritual nature of solitude. He compares it with aloneness, which is very different to loneliness:

> “…This aloneness is not aching, fearsome loneliness.  It is the aloneness of being; it is uncorrupted, rich, and complete. That tamarind tree has no existence other than being itself.  So is this aloneness.  One is alone, like the fire, like the flower, but one is not aware of its purity and of its immensity.  One can truly communicate only when there is aloneness.  Being alone is not the outcome of denial, of self-enclosure.  Aloneness is the purgation of all motives, of all pursuits of desire, of all ends.  Aloneness is not an end product of the mind.  You cannot wish to be alone.  Such a wish is merely an escape from the pain of not being able to commune.
>
> “Loneliness, with its fear and ache, is isolation, the inevitable action of the self.  This process of isolation, whether expansive or narrow, is a product of confusion, conflict, and sorrow. Isolation can never give birth to aloneness; the one has to cease for the other to be. Aloneness is indivisible and loneliness is separation.  That which is alone is pliable and so enduring.  Only the alone can commune with that which is causeless, the immeasurable.  To the alone, life is eternal; to the alone there is no death. The alone can never cease to be.” ( Krishnamurti, p. 17) Krishnamurti, J., Commentaries on Living. The Theosophical Publishing House, Wheaton, Ill. U.S.A. 1967.

Comment: amazing this is...

Answer (score 1):

To insist emptiness is the reality without having realized what the words mean brings no benefit..  in order to become realized one must train in both merit/virtues and wisdom.  Through gathering the two accumulations of merit and wisdom one can arrive at the perfectly awakened state.

What is your question?  The entire world is rather magical!

Comment: I'm not debating what is magical or not. I'll ask simply again: I talk to beings I feel/see with more than five senses, I see more, I know .... I want it to be simple and clear as earth. in this second world, in which through meditation I reach so much, is the goal the same. here i'm not only me, I'm not alone, and I'm asking is it an illusion, a mind trick to avoid, or something to learn, emptiness is without it. that I sense. but I don't know if to treat this second world any differently - like earth (dharma, sensitivity... ) or like mind let it fly away, concentrating on silence?

Comment: Ah ok, I understand more clearly your query.  Yes, the goal is always the same: the end of suffering.  Even if we suffer in a dream, we want it to go away.  If we are happy in a dream, we want it to last, but everything changes and there is no solid ground to stand on.  That is Ok!  You are perhaps more sensitive than the average personage so befriend all beings when possible.  Please check out the Metta Sutra! =)

Comment: @dalila http://quotes.justdharma.com/love-for-all-beings/ is something wonderful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about all that but there isn't much magical about "seeing reality as it is", meaning consistantly focusing on something arising in your own experience, as it arises, moment by moment , in a nonreactive, nonconceptual and impartial way. If something magical seeming  does happen then see it as it is and it won't be  magical anymore because it was seen without concepts such as "magical".

Comment: its true. but we need the word on the way. and they r fine as limited as they r. they help as move and be what we are. more and more at list. there is something magical - love. and its amazing to find it, again and again. I got it. today is new. tomorrow is another  day. tnx

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the words of the Buddha weren't useful and necessary. May you be happy and know boundless friendliness with all beings :)